# couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 while trying to start mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

After typing `mongo`
It is showing

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.13
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Also, the MongoDB campus showing `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

For `mongosh`

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6341cd406845432d371fc4b3
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.0
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Mongod Service also not starting

```
root@jahid:/home/jahid# sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-10-09 12:48:22 +06; 9min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 28523 (code=exited, status=14)

Oct 09 12:48:21 jahid systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 09 12:48:22 jahid systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Oct 09 12:48:22 jahid systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Is `mongod` running?

Comment: No it also error

Comment: sudo systemctl status mongod

● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-10-09 01:54:16 +06; 3min 2s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 16225 (code=exited, status=14)

Comment: `mongod` needs to be running successfully before `mongosh` or `compass` will be able to connect to it.

Comment: Check the mongod log file, typically at `var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit no log file was found on that location.

Comment: It works for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/823288/mongodb-loads-but-breaks-returning-status-14 at last.

Comment: That's not possible. Check your config file which is defined in `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` (typically `/etc/mongod.conf`) the [log file path](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-systemLog.path)